# Lightning Page with custom components added- Component does not refresh after saving the record on page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have added a lightning component to custom object page, which takes the data from DB and displays data in a table.
When I edit a Custom Object record and click on save I expected my component also refreshes with a page but it doesn't and shows old data. any inputs?

Comment: Can you paste minimal required snippet of your code?

Answer (score 1):

It will not happen until and unless you have some kind of functionality written in your component which will check for change in the data (which is edit here). I will suggest you to go through [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_handling_record_change.htm) to understand what you can do when there is a record change.

Basically you need to fire some event and then in your component, catch the event and perform your business logic. This is known as [pub-sub pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern).